# cbind items from multiple lists recursively

Tags: r, list, join, cbind

Given three (or `n` lists):

```
one   <- list(a=1:2,b="one")
two   <- list(a=2:3,b="two")
three <- list(a=3:4,b="three")
```

What would be a more efficient way of `cbind`ind each list item across the `n` lists, to get this result?

```
mapply(cbind,mapply(cbind,one,two,SIMPLIFY=FALSE),three,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

$a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4

$b
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]   
[1,] "one" "two" "three"
```

This works okay when `n` is `2` or `3` but is quickly going to become ludicrously complex.
Is there a more efficient variation on this? I have seen similar questions on S.O. but have struggled to adapt them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or like this:

```
mapply(cbind, one, two, three)
```

Or like this:

```
mylist <- list(one, two, three)
do.call(mapply, c(cbind, mylist))
```

Comment: You're kidding me? I swear I tried that first one, but obviously I didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Use `Reduce` and `Map` (`Map` being a simple wrapper for `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`

```
Reduce(function(x,y) Map(cbind, x, y),list(one, two,three))
```

When using `Reduce` or most of the functional programming base functions in R, you usually can't pass arguments in `...` so you normally need to write a small anonymous function to do what you want.

Comment: Excellent! I had played with `Reduce` but was getting nowhere fast. Thanks muchly.

Answer (score 2):

```
sep.list <- unlist(list(one, two, three), recursive = FALSE)
lapply(split(sep.list, names(sep.list)), do.call, what = cbind)
```